# Interpolation using dot notation in c#

Tags: c#

How can I achieve interpolation when using dot notation. The below code (later part ) may be wrong in syntax or concept but I just wanted to show, what I would like to do. Consider this

```
public class IDs {
    List<Object> UIObjects = new List<Object>();

    public objectClass<type1> var1;
    public objectClass<type2> var2;
    ...

    var1 = new objectClass<type1>();
    var2 = new objectClass<type2>();
    ...

    UIObjects.Add(var1);
    UIObjects.Add(var2);
    ...

}

public class otherClass {

    accessor = new IDs ();
    string myconst = "constant"

    foreach (Object item in accessor.UIObjects ){

    myconst_{item.getString()} = accessor.{item}.createObject(); 
    // how can I achieve this so 

    //  constant_var1 holds accessor.var1.createObject(); 
    //   constant_var2 holds accessor.var2.createObject(); 
    //    and so on ...

}
```

Comment: C# is a statically typed language. You are not supposed to do such kind of things, neither can you.

Comment: so whats the alternative. currently I have several lines of code with `var1` , `var2` and so on .. in later part of the above code

Comment: You might use Reflection. But it's better to design a good solution where no Reflection is required. Reflection code is slow and hard to maintain. It is also not readable and error-prone.

Comment: Use an array or other collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you cannot do exactly what you are trying to do.  I would recommend trying to use a `Dictionary<string, Object>` to keep track of your objects, like this:

```
public class otherClass{

  accessor = new IDs ();
  string myconst = "constant"
  Dictionary<string, Object> uiObjects = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

  foreach (Object item in accessor.UIObjects )
  {
    uiObjects.Add($"{myconst}_{item.ToString()}", item.createObject());
  }

}
```

This way, you have your objects paired with your naming convention in a searchable structure.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and let you know

Comment: That approach worked with some changes in code. I'll edit to correct in case someone is looking for same

Comment: The correct syntax is this  `foreach ( KeyValuePair<object,dynamic> item in accessor.UIObjects)
            {
                uiObjects.Add($"{item.Key.ToString()}", item.Value.createObject());

            }`  . Not sure why  you didn't accept edit.